# Store Non-Static Object in Class with Static Functions

Tags: c++, static

i have two classes (non-static) A & (static) B.
I am trying to store Object A into B so that i can use its functions in funcB().
However i do know that static classes cannot store non-static variables & functions. is there anyway to get pass this rather than converting Class A into a static class?

```
class A
{
   public:
          A();
          void funcA();
   private:
          int A;
};

class B
{
   public:
         B(A *objA);
         static void funcB();
   private:
         A *objA;
};
```

edit:
I stated static class to make it easier to explain. i did not know the correct term.
So the question is actually: How do i use a non-static member from a static function?

Comment: Why not pass a pointer or reference of A to funcB?

Comment: "Static classes" do not exist and your question makes no sense. Please explain why you think you need this.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static class". Maybe you mean a singleton class who, conceptually, only have static members. Also, *instances* of your "static class" can have non-static members. Only that static methods cannot use those non-static members for they need an instance for them to be used.

Comment: Sorry i said static classes as it was easier to explain. i do know that they do not exist in c++. but static functions do. However, when declaring static functions, i am unable to use the *objA Pointer. i need this because, the class A, links to many other classes and has stored many other information. Class B on the other hand, has to be static due to some windows API threading condition.

Comment: @MarkGarcia how do you declare an instance such that the static methods can use the non-static members?

Comment: @null, How would that work? Static members can be used/called without an instance. What instance's non-static members do you propose it uses?

Comment: @chris sorry but i do not understand what do you mean by what do i propose it uses?

Comment: @null, Static members cannot access non-static members because static members can be used without creating an object first. Each object has its own set of non-static members. How would it know what set of non-static members to use if it could access non-static members?

Comment: @null maybe you need a static `A *objA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access anything that is specific to an instance of a class from a static function by itself.  A static function has no "this" pointer (the compiler passes a pointer to the instance of the object calling the function for non-static functions).  You can get around this by passing a pointer to the object you want to modify, but then why are you using a static function?  My advice would be to avoid what it seems like you are trying to do, but I provided 2 ways to do it below (as a good learning example).

See below for an example of using

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
   public:
    A(int value) : a(value){}
          void funcA();
   public:
          int a;
};

class B
{
   public:
         B()
         {
             objA = new A(12);
         }

         void funcB2()
         {
             B::funcB(*objA);
         }

         static void funcB(A const & value)
         {
            cout << "Hello World! " << value.a << endl;
         }

   private:
         A *objA;
};

int main()
{
    A a(10);
    B::funcB(a);

    B b;
    b.funcB2();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should not make design like this. A static function is initialized when the non-static members are not ready. You said "the class A, links to many other classes and has stored many other information. Class B on the other hand, has to be static due to some windows API threading condition." . In this case, can you change your design and turn A into static class?

Comment: if i turn A into a static class, then the many other classes that includes will be affected. this will be a problem. i am actually using windows FileSystemWatcher which requires static methods. :(